# DynamoDB: Table Schema fot text searching

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I moving some data from MySQL to DynamoDB. Now I have a problem on schema design to fit all my needs. My Table in MySQL has schema like this:

```
userid - int
datetimemillis - int
typeid - int
string1 - string
string2 - string
string3 - string
string4 - string
```

Primary key is build with userid and datetimemillis

I need to do queries like this:

1. retrieve every row for particular userid
2. retrieve every row for particular userid and typeid
3. retrieve every row for particular userid and typeid that string1-4 contains specific string

I am able to do 1. and 2. query using userId as hashkey, typeId as local secondary index (range key is needed for deleting all records with particular userid). Is there any option that I can make third query without using scan? What are my possibilities? Use CloudSearch? Or other amazon service? If I need to change my schema please tell me. Price does not matter, it only must work, even if I would have to use fifty additional services and dynamodb tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do an exact string match with String1-4 you can use more local secondary indexes. DynamoDB supports up to 5 local secondary indexes.

But (I am thinking this is what you want) if you are trying to search for a specific contains inside one of those strings I would use something like solr to index all of those strings and its corresponding userId in solr and cross reference the userId from the resultset you get for a solr search with the HashKey in your dynamodb user table.