# Text search for DynamoDB Field?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to have `CONTAINS` operation on one of the fields for an infrequently updated DynamoDB table. Is there a recommended way to augment processing to avoid `SCAN`? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808249/search-text-in-dynamodb-break-up-tables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131549/dynamodb-table-schema-fot-text-searching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966080/dynamodb-query-with-comparison-operators

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057005/retrieve-all-items-with-a-column-beginning-with-specified-text-on-dynamodb